# What does $||f_n||_{\sup}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ converges uniformly on $D$, prove:
>   $||f_n||_{\sup}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Is the converse true? Prove or
>   give a counterexample.

But I can't understand what "$||f_n||_{\sup}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$" exactly means. Unless it's talking about the $n$th tail of the sequence, shouldn't $||f_n||_{\sup}$ will be a fixed value? But $f_n$ seems to be a sequence rather than $n$th tail of some other sequence.

As for my attempt to solve the problem, I am stating that $f_k\to 0$ by $n^{th}$ term test since $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ is convergent for all $x\in D$. Following from this, can I say $|f_k|\to 0$ as well?

Comment: $\|f_n\|_{\sup}$ is a real number depending on $n$.

Comment: I think $\,\|f_n\|_{\rm sup}\,$ is a real-valued sequence.

Comment: $\|f_n\|_{\text{sup}}$ is the supremum of $|f_n|$ on $D$. It is called the supremum or the uniform norm of $f_n$.

Comment: Just to clarify, so for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I am finding the $\sup\{f_n(x) : x\in D \}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k$ converges uniformly on $D$ implies that the sequence $f_k$ is dependent on $x\in D$.

So, we need to show that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)$ converges uniformly on $D$, then

$$\lim_{k\to \infty }\sup_{x\in D}|f_k(x)|=0$$

Let $S_n(x)$ denote the sequence of partial sums of the series of interest.  If the series converges uniformly on $D$ to $S(x)$, then given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a number $N$ such that

$$\left|S_n(x)-S(x)\right|<\epsilon/2$$

whenever $n>N$ for all $x\in D$.

Then, given $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
|f_{n+1}(x)|&=|S_{n+1}(x)-S_n(x)|\\\\
&\le |S_{n+1}(x)-S(x)|+|S_n(x)-S(x)|\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>N$ for all $x\in D$.  And this completes the proof.